# Which Android Emulator is better for testing Kivy applications?

Tags: android, python, android-emulator, kivy

I've just finished my Kivy application and it works great in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64-bit). Now I want to test it on an Android system, so I follow [these steps](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#buildozer) in the official Kivy docs and finally (after some troubles) I could create the .APK file. Since I didn't hace a real android phone or tablet, I installed the Genymotion Android Emulator which is actually emulating a Samsung Galaxy S4 - 4.3 - API 18 - 1080x1920. When trying to open my application.apk file I'm receiving:

[image]

That's all, there's no more information.

Does anybody experimented something like this? Is there any Android emulator which works better when it's testing Kivy applications?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The normal Android emulator works fine. Make sure it is using Android 4+ and has hardware GPU acceleration enabled.